# Status 404 error while implementing Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I coded everything I need and assume I imported all required spring jars below is my code. Js file using angular framework. login object is successfully populated required fields.But  http://localhost:8081/MayuriSelection/registerUser.htm is giving 404.

```
$scope.Register = function(){
            $scope.register = {};
            $scope.register.usrName = $scope.usrName;
            $scope.register.email = $scope.email;
            $scope.register.pswd = $scope.pswd;
            $scope.register.confirmpswd = $scope.confirmpswd;
            console.log($scope.register);
            $http({
                method : "POST",
                url : "registerUser.htm",
                data : $scope.register
            }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
                $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
            }, function myError(response) {
                $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
            });

        }
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MayuriSelection</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>HelloCustomer</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>HelloCustomer</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HelloCustomer-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.mayuri.controller" /> -->

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

LoginController.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
/**
 * @author sagar reddy
 *
 */
package com.mayuri.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class LoginController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registerUser.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(){
        String message = "Hi Im here";
        System.out.println(message);
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you link to `http://localhost:8081/MayuriSelection/registerUser.htm`?
If you just copy link to browser you will get 404 because this is GET request and in controller you are defining just POST method!  Are you getting 404 response in angular method defined above or when you are clicking on the link?

Comment: How do you get this part `/MayuriSelection/` in the link? I don't see this on the RequestMapping!

Comment: I am getting 404 when I call above function 'Register' in js which call "http://localhost:8081/MayuriSelection/registerUser.htm". It is appending '/MayuriSelection/' as it is the project name. Please correct me if my approach is wrong.

Comment: Sagar, What is the purpose of this? Are you starting to learn Spring MVC. if so, please start with some tutorials on Spring Site and use Java config instead of XML config. Or you can also start using Spring boot. You are dealing with very low level things and those things are already taken care..

Comment: Thanks Vimal, but can Spring boot be understood without out prior knowledge of Spring MVC?